# OkHttp Authenticator sometimes does not call authenticate with multiple Retrofit instances

Tags: authentication, retrofit2, okhttp, authenticator

I have two different `Retrofit` instances for two different APIs. I also have two different `OkHttp3` clients but they share the same `Authenticator` because the auth token is the same for both APIs.

The problem is that when the token expires then *sometimes* (but almost always) one of the `Retrofit`/`OkHttpClient` objects will not call the `Authenticator`'s `authenticate` method on HTTP 401. It will happily make API calls and all will end with 401 and the authenticator is completely ignored. In this case, when the second `Retrofit` makes an API call it will receive 401 and the `authenticate` is called, token is refreshed, and everything is back to normal. Including the second `Retrofit` API, which was failing all calls with 401.

Bigger problem is that this behaviour is random but the failure is more on than half of token expirations. We have tried two `Retrofit` instances with one shared `OkHttp3` client, then two `OkHttp3` clients with shared interceptors and authenticator and finally also not-shared interceptors and authenticators. And even in the last case, with everything having its own instance, the authenticate is not called on some 401 errors.

`Interceptor`s work, they inject the old token into headers, just the `Authenticator`'s `authenticate` method is not called on every HTTP 401 error.

When stepping through debugger this never happens and the authenticate is always called. This looks like a multi-threading issue to me. Instant run is disabled in the Android Studio. Running on real device with Android 6.

**EDIT:**
OkHttp 3.10.0, Retrofit 2.4.0, android compile SDK 27 and build tools 28.0.1

Comment: were you able to fix this issue ? I am having a simliar one where multiple tokens are refreshed and for some reason we don't see any 401

Comment: @user12865 No entirely, but the root cause is described in another SO question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831568/okhttp-authenticator-sometimes-does-not-call-authenticate-on-http-401 This looks like a bug in OkHttp and/or Retrofit. I was not able to create a small sample for them to fix it though :( One solution is to use specific versions of OkHttp and Retrofit.