# OkHttp Authenticator sometimes does not call authenticate on HTTP 401

Tags: authentication, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp, authenticator

I have an issue that `OkHttp`'s `Authenticator` does not call the `authenticate` method in some cases of HTTP 401 errors. Interceptors are always called, but authenticator is sometimes called and sometimes not. Once it does not call it it will not call it for several minutes and all network calls will fail with HTTP 401. Then after 5-6 minutes it will "unstuck" and call the `authenticate` method again.

I use it for refreshing token. If the token expiration is set to one hour, there are no issues, but when we set the expiration to one minute (for testing) the authenticator stops working.

When quickly stepping through code in the debugger the `authenticate` method is entered, but event its first line is not executed, it just exits from the method. I have a log as the very first line which is not printed. I have tried both `synchronised` access and non-synchronised. The authenticator is written in Kotlin.

This is a continuation of issue described in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811938/okhttp-authenticator-sometimes-does-not-call-authenticate-with-multiple-retrofit). I have found out that it even does not work with one `Retrofit` instance with one `OkHttp` client, so I have created a new question.

This is happening with OkHttp 3.10.0/3.11.0, Retrofit 2.4.0, android compile SDK 27 and build tools 28.0.1. On real devices with Android 6 and 8.1, debug and release builds, so it looks like it does not

**EDIT:**

After more debugging I have found out that the authenticator works flawlessly with OkHttp 3.9.1 + Retrofit 2.3.0. Anything newer will not work for frequent HTTP 401 errors. Using OkHttp 3.10.0 or newer with Retrofit 2.3.0 does not work and also Retrofit 2.4.0 with OkHttp 3.9.1 does not work. Also other combinations of newer OkHttp+Retrofit do not work.

One more extra information is that I use the RxJava2 adapter for Retrofit 2 (`com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2`), always the same version as the Retrofit library. I am using RxJava2 2.1.9 and I have just tried the latest 2.2.2, still not working except for the old OkHttp+Retrofit combination.

Comment: If you can isolate this intoa standalone test case, we can fix it in OkHttp.

Comment: @JesseWilson I will try to prepare a small Android app with testing server by the end of this week

Comment: @JesseWilson I am still working on a small test for this case. I am having problem with `MockServer` that the `Route` is null in the `Authenticator`'s `authenticate` method thus the test fails with `IllegalArgumentException`.